# Find base with known 2 sides and height

Tags: trigonometry

I'm losing my mind trying to solve a problem and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

**Problem:**
The figure below shows a model ferris wheel that a child has constructed using a toy building
kit. The wheel has a radius of 40 cm, and the center of the wheel is 45 cm above the floor. An
electric motor turns the wheel at 4 rotations per minute.

b) The support struts AB and AC are each 50 cm long. Find the distance between B and C.

[image]

**My answer:**

- Side AB: 50
- Side AC: 50
- Height: 45

I split triangle into 2 right triangles with hypotenuse: 50 and height: 45.

To get half of base, I use Pythagorean theorem: $\sqrt{50^2 - 45^2}$ = 21.8.

I multiply 2x and get base as: 43.6

I would think it's a correct answer, however solution in the book to this question is: $2*\sqrt{19}$ = 8.7cm

**Is there an error in the book I'm using or I missed something?**

Comment: Your work is correct.

Comment: Note that your answer is $5\sqrt{19}$. Did the book actually say $8.7$? If not, then the book simply has a typo.

Comment: Thanks Jaap for the clue. Actually it reaffirms that indeed it's most likely typo in the book.

Comment: Not $5\sqrt{19}$.  Full base is twice that.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct.  But the book may not be wrong if you accidentally read the answer to a different problem. 
That is easy to do when the answers are all piled together in the back, and in some cases given only for some problems.  Please check that.

Comment: I've checked like 10 times and the answer to the problem a) was correct. It must be a typo. By the way, the book is "Precalculus Mathematics for Precalculus" - James Stewart. The book in my opinion is great, but I was surprised as it's first typo I noticed.